# RxJava/RxKotlin complains about accessing views

Tags: android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-kotlin

I have the following call to retrieve some data from server and update the UI according to response.

```
    poiAPIService.getPoiDetails(poiId!!)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnSubscribe { showProgressBar(true) }
            .doFinally { showProgressBar(false) }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe(
                    { poiDetails ->
                        bindPoiDetails(poiDetails)
                    },
                    {
                        (getActivity() as MainOverviewActivity).fragmentControl.hidePoiDetailsFragment()
                    })

}
```

It complains about showProgressBar that the Views are only accessable on thread that created them.
If I change the call like this, everything seems to be fine again.

```
showProgressBar(true)
poiAPIService.getPoiDetails(poiId!!)
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe(
                { poiDetails ->
                    showProgressBar(false)
                    bindPoiDetails(poiDetails)
                },
                {
                    showProgressBar(false)
                    (getActivity() as MainOverviewActivity).fragmentControl.hidePoiDetailsFragment()
                })

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you tried to do something like this...

```
poiAPIService.getPoiDetails(poiId!!)
        .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .doOnSubscribe { showProgressBar(true) }
        .doFinally { showProgressBar(false) }
        .subscribe(
                { poiDetails ->
                    bindPoiDetails(poiDetails)
                },
                {
                    (getActivity() as MainOverviewActivity).fragmentControl.hidePoiDetailsFragment()
                })
```

pay attention to `observeOn` and `subscribeOn`

Looks like you use `observeOn` and `subscribeOn` not correctly...
take a look to [How RXJava Scheduler/Threading works for different operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53983854/how-rxjava-scheduler-threading-works-for-different-operator/53998063#53998063)

Answer (score 3):

I have done by using below code, using RxJava 2.x

```
 poiAPIService.getPoiDetails(poiId!!)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnSubscribe(new Consumer < Disposable >() {
                @Override
                public void accept(Disposable disposable) throws Exception {
                    showProgressBar(true);
                }
            })
            .doFinally(new Action () {
                @Override
                public void run() throws Exception {
                    showProgressBar(false);
                }
            })
            .subscribe(/**your subscription here**/);
```

Try using above code and let me know.