# How RXJava Scheduler/Threading works for different operator?

Tags: android, rx-java, scheduler

Can anyone please help me to explain which scheduler are running below code?

```
Completable.complete()                 
.subscribeOn(http://Schedulers.io  ())                 
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())                 
.delay(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)                 
.doOnComplete(() -> liveDataState.postValue(""))                 
.subscribe()
```

My question is which schedulers are **delay(), doOnComplete() and subscribe()** are using `io` or `mainThread`?

Comment: anything below onbserveon switches to android main thread

Comment: Then why state.setValue("") not working?

Comment: what is state. also you can log to see on which thread you are on with Thread.currentThread().getName()

Comment: Each operator's documentation specifies which scheduler it works on. For example, that [delay](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Completable.html#delay-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) runs on the computation scheduler.

Answer (score 4):

After digging into RxJava threading last two days found the rule of thumbs for handling RxJava Threading/Scheduling:

- `observeOn` works only downstream operator
- `subscribeOn` works for both downstream and upstream operator
- Consecutive/Multiple `subscribeOn` do not change the thread
- Consequent `observeOn` do change the thread for downstream oerator
- Unlike with `subscribeOn()`, we can use `observeOn()` multiple times for
  seamless thread switching
- Operator like `delay()`, `interval()` have default scheduler and can change the downstream scheduler as well

**So, for my case:**

```
Completable.complete()   // IO scheduler based on subscribeOn scheduler           
.subscribeOn(http://Schedulers.io  ())                 
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())                 
.delay(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)   // Default Computation scheduler              
.doOnComplete(() -> liveDataState.postValue(""))  // Computation scheduler by delay scheduler             
.subscribe()  // Computation scheduler by delay as well
```

Also, you can look into the marble diagram for more understanding:

[image]